# Good reference material for graph theory

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Could anyone please suggest either a book or some reference material either online or as printed material for graph theory?

Answer (score 1):

[*Graph Theory*](http://diestel-graph-theory.com) by Diestel is a good reference which is freely available online.

Answer (score 0):

1)As a reference book Graph theory by Narsingh Deo is  easy to follow,

2)Also Discrete Maths by Kenneth Rosen is a good book for problem solving

3)for Algorithms in Graph theory You can study and standard Algorithm text or the Coursera MOOC on Algorithm is a good one